# react typescript constructor state vs property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have following typescript code:

```
interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> { }

interface State {
  users: Array<User>;
}

class UsersTable extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {users: []};

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(`${apiUrl}/users`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(users => {
        this.setState({users});
      });
  }

  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    const {users} = this.state;

    if (!users.length) {
      return('...Loading');
    }

    return(
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <Table className={classes.table}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Id</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {users.map(u => (
              <TableRow key={u.Id}>
                <TableCell numeric>{u.Id}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
export default withRoot(withStyles(styles)(UsersTable));
```

Its won't compile with error:
*property 'Id' does not exist on type 'never'.*
As i understand this.state.users get type 'never',
However if i add constructor:

```
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {users: []};
  }
```

It's compile just fine and state got correct type.
So what's the difference between first approach and second one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you have the assignment `state = {...}` in the class, the type of state is determined by the type of whatever you assign `state` to, rather than the base class definition. This meas that the type of state here is `{users: never[]}` (though I thought it was `any[]`, but that must be a difference in newer typescript versions).

Specify the type explicitly, eg. `state: State = { users: [] }`, or `state = { users: [] } as State`.